# picture is delocated or an empty page before and after the picture

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I have been having some troubles with the insertion of picture in my document(pdf) when using latex. At first, when I inserted the picture, the picture was delocating. this was the code.

```
\begin{figure}

  \begin{center}

    \makebox[\linewidth]{
       \includegraphics[width=20cm ]{img/myImage.jpg}}

       \caption{This is my image}
       \label{fig:ToUseWithReference}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Then I some how fixed it this way.

```
\begin{figure}[p]

  \vspace*{-2cm}
    \makebox[\linewidth]{
      \includegraphics[width=20cm ]{img/myImage.jpg}}

      \caption{This is my image}
      \label{fig:ToUseWithReference}

\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

But this brought up another problem. there is always an empty page left before and after the image is displayed even if I am displaying on a free and empty page. Does anyone knows what is wrong.

Comment: I have just found out how to solve it. just removed %clearpage, \vspace*{-2cm}. then changed \begin{figure}[p] to \begin{figure}[H].

Comment: Please answer your question, if you think it will help other later on. Or you delete your question in order to close this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since I was suggested to answer my question for the purpose of knowledge sharing, here is my answer.

```
\begin{figure}[H]

    \makebox[\linewidth]{
      \includegraphics[width=20cm ]{img/myImage.jpg}}

    \caption{This is my image}
    \label{fig:ToUseWithReference}

\end{figure}
```

I solved this by changing the parameter [p] to [H] where H Places the float at precisely the location in the LaTeX code. see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions then I removed \clearpage and \vspace*{-2cm}